# How to merge IP addresses and ignore wrong IP addresses Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, merge, ip

I have an array of arrays containing subnets, one of the subnets is wrong (is missing one octet) and I would like to merge them and ignore the wrong one.

I have the following code:

```
subnets = ["149.62.168.0/24"], ["134.247.2.0/24"], ["159.226.92.0/24","159.8.57/22"]

require 'netaddr'

subnet.each do |net|
  begin
  merged_subnets = NetAddr.merge(net)
  rescue ArgumentError => error
    puts error
  end
  puts merged_subnets
end
```

This code gives me the following output:

```
149.62.168.0/24
134.247.2.0/24
One of the provided CIDR addresses raised the following errors: 159.8.57 is invalid (IPv4 requires (4) octets).
```

However, what I was expecting was:

```
 149.62.168.0/24
 134.247.2.0/24
 159.226.92.0/24
 One of the provided CIDR addresses raised the following errors: 159.8.57 is invalid (IPv4 requires (4) octets).
```

I don't understand why the subnet **159.226.92.0/24** doesn't appear in the output.

Comment: Technically that should be `subnets = [ ["149..."], [ ... ], ... ]` where there's surrounding outer square brackets. What you have there works but it's misleading. You're actually creating an array of arrays. `flatten` could help iterate over all of the individual elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple errors.

- You have an inconsistency in your initialization of the `subnets` array. The last value has two subnets in the same sub array: `["159.226.92.0/24","159.8.57/22"]` is the array causing the error you see and hence it is throwing both values away, which is why you don't see `159.226.92.0/24` in the final result.
- You are iterating over `subnet` which is a typo, I believe you meant `subnets`.
- You are overwriting `merged_subnets` on each iteration.

I fixed the code:

```
subnets = ["149.62.168.0/24"], ["134.247.2.0/24"], ["159.226.92.0/24"], ["159.8.57/22"]

require 'netaddr'

merged_subnets = []

subnets.each do |net|
  begin
    merged_subnets << NetAddr.merge(net)
  rescue ArgumentError => error
    puts error
  end
end
```

`merged_subnets` is now `[["149.62.168.0/24"], ["134.247.2.0/24"], ["159.226.92.0/24"]]`

Comment: Thank you @DiegoSalazar, yes `subnet` was a typo. I get the subnets from YAML files and some YAMLs have more than one subnet, that's why the last array had two subnets, instead of one, like the other two. But I'll try to separate them, in order to reach the desired output! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`159.226.92.0/24` doesn't appear in the output because of your call to `NetAddr#merge`.

`NetAddr#merge` takes your array (in this case, `["159.226.92.0/24","159.8.57/22"]`), parses each address in the array, and merges the parsed addresses. In pseudo-Ruby, that'd be this:

```
def merge(ary)
    parsed = []
    for addr in ary do
        parsed << parse(addr)
    end

    merge_parsed(parsed)
end
```

As you can see, if the call to `parse(addr)` fails, the entire method will fail and raise an error, returning no results. Since `159.226.92.0/24` is in a subnet array with the invalid address `159.8.57/22`, the `merge` call on the whole array fails, and you don't get any results.